# SSIS and Bamboo Integration using Bit Bucket

Tags: ssis, bitbucket, bamboo, aws-code-deploy

I want to deploy an **SSIS** package to SQL Server **SSDB cataglog**, using Bamboo Continuous integration, i am using **Bitbucket** as repository. 
Can anyone help me get started ...

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Yes I have pushed my SSIS solution to BitBucket and configured Bamboo with my BitBucket Repository, but next i dont know how to deploy that SSIS package to SQL Server using Bamboo

Answer (score 0):

The following blog talk about Atlassian Bamboo and AWS CodeDeploy integration: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/announcing-atlassian-bitbucket-support-for-aws-codedeploy/